# How to use sed to replace an environment variable

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, sed

I have the following strings in a file

```
$ENVVAR
someText ($ENVVAR)
```

I want to use `sed` so that only the second occurence of the variable is replaced with the value of the environment variable

so

```
$ENVVAR
someText (value of env variable)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a case for some <strike>ugly</strike> fancy quoting. Single quotes stop shell parameter expansions, and double quotes to allow them.

You can think of quotes as on-off switches in a `sed` expression, closing one type of quoting and opening another like this: `'strong'"weak"'strong'`

Using `$USER` as an example:

```
$ cat file
$USER
some text ($USER)

$ sed 's/($USER)/('"$USER"')/' file
$USER
some text (zanna)
```